# Angular Velocity

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

When angular velocity has a given value in the problem and I want to take the vector cross product of it with vector position; Does it have $\hat k$ component or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a rod AB hinged at end A rotating with angular speed $w$ in the clockwise sense as seen from top.

Now, direction of $w$ is $-\hat k$ (considering right handed system).
For all intents and purposes that is, if you want to take the cross product, you must use $-\hat k$ with the value given in the problem.